# How to access keosd API like create wallet, what are the input parameter

Tags: nodeos, cleos, eosio.token, keosd

I am new with eosio, and I want to create a wallet and sub wallet.
I just took reference of [https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/index][1]
and while going through the document I found that keosd is the one which helps me to provide the API.
while I run the **keosd** command

```
api url: /v1/wallet/create
api url: /v1/wallet/create_key
api url: /v1/wallet/get_public_keys
api url: /v1/wallet/import_key
api url: /v1/wallet/list_keys
api url: /v1/wallet/list_wallets
api url: /v1/wallet/lock
api url: /v1/wallet/lock_all
api url: /v1/wallet/open
api url: /v1/wallet/remove_key
api url: /v1/wallet/set_timeout
api url: /v1/wallet/sign_digest
api url: /v1/wallet/sign_transaction
api url: /v1/wallet/unlock
api url: /v1/node/get_supported_apis
```

I could not find the proper documentation where I can see what are the input parameter and what is the output.
So if anyone know please share the thought or any link where i can see the soluation.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official documentation for `keosd` here: https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/v2.1/keosd/index

This contains everything from how to guides, to descriptions of how you can edit the `config.ini` files and run individual commands.